# Any chance of downloading ALL content I posted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, questions, answers, profile-page

Is there any chance of downloading ALL content I posted on Stack Overflow?

Is it possible to retrieve all questions/answers of mine? Or could I use some PHP-based crawler which will download all my questions/answers? Something like my Stack Overflow offline archive, but just where did I answer/posted question?

Comment: at first i thought this said downvoting not downloading.. whew, need more coffee.

Comment: NoOOoO please I'm scaried

Comment: @BrAvada Kedavran, don't worry, so did I.

Comment: See also [Dump of my own Stack Exchange content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269804/157730)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here you go: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1505/get-all-your-posts-and-comments?User=764846. There is a "download results" link, feel free to use it. You can also change the query to include more data. Note that the data is somewhat outdated, I think it is only updated every few weeks.

Comment: It's a monthly data dump I believe.

Comment: I think that it isn't cached as it showed me todays posts

Comment: So many thanks Wladimir. Could I have another query for answers, too

Comment: Entries with PostTypeId should be answers, no?

Comment: @genesis: I meant "entries with PostTypeId 2"