# What is the best way to download a list of stack exchange questions for offline browsing?

Tags: feature-request

I have about 600 favorite questions from the stack exchange network that I want to compile into a single pdf to read offline. Clearly clicking on each one is not an option(repetitive tasks may be for some people, not for me). 
[image]
Has anyone done this before or have ideas about how to go about it? I was thinking maybe WinHttrack might give me an html file with a lot of fiddling of options but I prefer a single pdf with all the questions scrolling linearly.

Has it ever been suggested that this be incorporated into stack exchange, similar to wikipedia's convert to pdf function?

### Solution:

After experimenting with many alternatives, the best way to do this is [run the following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/698216), which I sorted by descending save date for my purposes:

```
SELECT P.Id AS [Post Link], 'https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/'+ CAST(P.Id AS nvarchar)
FROM Votes V, Posts P, Users U, VoteTypes Vt
WHERE
P.Id = V.PostId
AND U.Id = V.UserId
AND Vt.Id = V.VoteTypeId
AND U.Id = '##UserId##'
AND Vt.Id = '5'
ORDER BY V.CreationDate DESC
```

Save the list as a csv file, download [chrono download manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon), copy the favorites in batches of 100 links (more than that gets you blocked for a period) to chrono. The url field of the new task looks like it accepts only 1 url, but you can paste as many as is needed already separated by new lines from the csv. Open nitro pro, click combine in the ribbon, and drag the files into the list. Right clicking files in explorer and combine with nitro only adds 44 of the files which would require you to select the rest and is error prone. *Important* you must convert the files to pdf while you are connected to the internet. Chrono doesn't download the images on the website. WinHTTrack does but it got me blocked after only about 10 favorite links downloaded from either google cache or stack exchange. Also, Adobe didn't render the mathjax when I tried it so nitro was a necessity for my pdf conversion. There are many free html to pdf options as well.

Comment: You could use the StackExchange API to download all of the questions - you would probably want to look at the [/users/{id}/favorites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users), [/posts/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids), and [/questions/{ids}/answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions) routes. Full documentation can be found [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269804/dump-of-my-own-stack-exchange-content