# What're my options for 'data preservation' for SE chat?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

Inspired by [reddit deciding to purge their chat history](https://www.engadget.com/reddit-is-removing-years-of-chats-and-messages-194558937.html?src=rss) with no warning(for the love of dog, don't!) and a current project of trying to back up the prompts of a defunct bot (and searching through chat's the easy way IMO)

Quite a lot of personal, 'micro' community and moderation history's stored in chat. While I guess one can do archive backups of public chat via various tools like the wayback machine, there's no 'formal' API or data dump for it.

While I'm hopeful that chat remains in at least maintenance mode - having some way to back up information archived to it, and occasionally the memories of folks long gone seems to be a nice thing.

What's my options for backing up chat 'externally'/offline? And for private chat, are there any considerations for knowledge preservation should the worst happen?

Comment: It's worth noting that downloading all of (public) chat isn't too hard; a CGCC user is currently in the process of doing that right now, actually. There're only ~60 million messages, so you only need to spend a few weeks slowly gathering transcripts

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can run some scraping script or software to do it. It just seems 'ugly'

Comment: You can [request a dump of your own chat logs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366720/377214). It will not include others' messages or messages in private rooms.

Comment: This might be a question for [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com) ... If chat is "subscriber content"' then it's licensed under a Creative Commons. The license doesn't prevent the company from deleting chat, but it does preserve your legal right to download, save, and re share, so long as you keep with the CC BY-SA license

Comment: * public chat, at least. Non-public chat doesn't seem like it would qualify.

Comment: Possibly but the 'legal' aspect isn't really how my brain works - If I'm *sueing* someone or waving legal threats, things are beyond saving :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike Well, it's fairly easy to download all the messages in JSON on a per-room basis. If you're really wanting to do all rooms, it should take less than a day for the approximately 130M messages on chat.SE (~64M), chat.SO (~56M), and chat.MSE (~10M), based on being able to do each of those in parallel and three quick tests of downloading 10k messages giving a range of 8.468 hours to 16.015 hours for 60M messages. I know I've used the SOCVR archiver to temporarily download in the ballpark of 1M messages a few times in the past to search for messages to clean up.

Comment: @AMtwo I don't think asking on [law.se] is needed. As far as I'm aware, the user contributed content on chat has always been explicitly under a CC BY-SA license. You'd need to do some research as to which license applied to which content (i.e. on what date(s) the specified license version changed, because chat was using a different CC BY-SA version at various times), but that's just research, rather than really a Law question.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog the GDPR information requests seem to work fundamentally different now, they are much smaller than before and only include explicitly private data like names, emails and IP addresses