# Can I obtain data about my Q&A on all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, data-analysis, activity

Is it possible to download the following data on my questions and answers on all Stack Exchange sites?

- The Stack Exchange site it appeared on (can be omitted as redundant if the full URL is provided).
- The URL, but NOT the content, of the question or answer.
- Date and time posted.
- For questions, the title (either original or current after edits, or both).
- For questions, the count of views.
- The net votes (I think that's also called the score).
- The count of comments.
- The count of edits.
- For answers, a boolean for whether it was accepted.
- For questions, its status, such as closed, deleted, etc., and the reason, such as "duplicate of ...".
- Any other such data that exists about my questions and answers, except for their content.

If there is not a specific facility for downloading that, what is the easiest way to access all those data?

Please note that this is not a duplicate of [*Dump of my own Stack Exchange content*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269804/dump-of-my-own-stack-exchange-content), which asked only for the content of the Q&A without any of the data I'm asking for. My question is the opposite of that question.